# multiple "else if"

Tags: macros, conditionals

When labelling theorems and such, the label often takes this form :

```
\label{th:pyth}
```

So when referring to theorems, we often write :

```
According to theorem \ref{th:pyth} ...
```

But there is a little bit of redundancy with "theorem" and "th", so i wanted to create a command that would look like `\refenv{th}{pyth}` and that would output `theorem 1`.
In order to do that, I would need to match the first argument to a string, so I tried this with the `boolexpr` package :

```
\usepackage{boolexpr}
\NewDocumentCommand{\refenv}{mm}{
    \switch
    \case{#1 = th} theorem
    \case{#1 = prop} proposition
    \case{#1 = coro} corollary
    \case{#1 = lem} lemma
    \case{#1 = prf} proof
    \case{#1 = def} definition
    \case{#1 = rem} remark
    \case{#1 = eq} equation
    \endswitch
    \ref{#1:#2}
}
```

Without success, since the `boolexpr` package only compares numbers.
How can I find an equivalent that does not require multiple nested `ifthenelse` commands?

Comment: Why not using `cleveref`?

Comment: It's a lot easier to look at the label string, if it starts with th, theorem etc. Latex has tools to check for this. Otherwise look at cleveref. I have an unpublished package that only uses the structure of the label string it self so it can be done.

Comment: `cleveref` has done the job as I wanted it to.

Comment: Please provide your own solution as an answer and mark it as solved after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a more flexible case switch function.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\refenv}{mm}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {th}{theorem}
    {prop}{proposition}
    {coro}{corollary}
    {lem}{lemma}
    {prf}{proof}
    {def}{definition}
    {rem}{remark}
    {eq}{equation}
   }
  {??}
  \nobreakspace\ref{#1:#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% just a couple of envs
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{def:important}
A \emph{definition} defines.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{th:main}
The main theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:best}
0=0
\end{equation}

We see that \refenv{th}{main} depends on \refenv{def}{important}
and \refenv{eq}{best}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it's better to use `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% just a couple of envs
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{def:important}
A \emph{definition} defines.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}\label{th:main}
The main theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:best}
0=0
\end{equation}

We see that \cref{th:main} depends on \cref{def:important}
and \cref{eq:best}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the manual of `cleveref` to see how to customize the references.

Answer (score 0):

The package `cleveref`, suggested by egreg, does everything I need, and does remove the redundancy, so no need to do else if shenanigans.